# How to send a pdf file on a WhatsApp number using c#.net

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, whatsapp

I have created a web application using angular (for user interface) and c#.net.
I want to send invoice (pdf file) on customer's WhatsApp no from my application.
How can I send pdf file on file? I did go through some links but I did not understand.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK WhatsApp is a *closed network* which you can't send messages from outside easily. To get an API to talk to your customers you should take a look at [WhatsApp Business API](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api) that allows this access if you pay for it.